# Is there way to create a true selfhosted .Net ( Core) wepApp without any proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, self-hosting

I can in ASP.NET and .NET Core create a selfhosted web service (WCF,REST, based on Kastrel or Katana and so on). But is there a way to create a full working web site, or SPA, may be based MVC ?

For example I can inside .NET Core Startup file add code:

```
 app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello World! {
          //insert your web site here :-)
          }");
        });
```

- but I should to create all html, js and so on code by myself. May be we have a better way ?

Of course I know that we have a big parts like ASP and so on - but we can't create selfhosted app, we need a web server - usually IIS !

Comment: You do not need a web server, just create a new Asp.Net Core Web Application in visual studio and it will run self hosted.

Comment: you can't set other address than localhost ( 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean that your self-hosted web server of visual studio is not accessible from the outside?

Assuming that your port forwarding and firewall are correctly configured. You need to change the bind address of your application:

```
new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    ...
    .UseUrls("http://*:80")
    ...;
```

#### Note:

This should never be used without reverse proxy.

More info about why this should not be done without reverse proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I would add a huge warning against doing this in a public application, this should only ever be used for intranet applications not accessible from the internet

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, could you explain a bit more why? I know that he would not really get the best performance because of the hundreds of (additional non-production processes), but with a good firewall setup, why would it be a problem?

Comment: 8 second I should wait

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Please read the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, ah ok you mean that. I just misunderstood you. Sure, that nginx (or any reverse proxy) should be used. I personally in my projects like to use nginx.